# Cannot log into the WiFi due to blocked website called hla2.safemovedm.com

Tags: wi-fi, lg-g3

I just got a new LG G3 running android 5.0. On my schools WiFi, there are blocked websites. When I try to connect to the school WiFi, it comes up with a terms and conditions screen (like the ones you see at Starbucks or other free WiFis), but it says that I am trying to access a blocked website called `hla2.safemovedm.com`.

I can bypass this by getting one of the teachers to log me into their administrative accounts, but I don't want to have to do this every time. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Might be related, but I found it hard to research further: http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-security-talk/358086-hotspot-login-assistant-possible-malware.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an app installed called 'Hotspot Login Assistant'? It appears as though it could be related to an app that attempts to log you into hotspots automatically.

I've found [several](http://hla.safemovedm.com/webping.html) [sites](http://hla2.safemovedm.com/homepage.html) on the safemovedm.com domain which imply that this is caused by 'Hotspot Login Assistant'.

Comment: I don't see an app called that... So you know another way i could remove it?

Comment: do you know how

Answer (score 1):

The app that makes calls to this site from my phone is the "Sprint Connections Optimizer" which is my phone company's network spy. If your service provider is Sprint then this is definitely your problem. It was tracking all my wi-fi connections in hopes of creating a dynamic map of networks to the benefit of Sprint, from which to steal bandwidth rather than giving me the unlimited access to their data network for which I have explicitly prepaid.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by going to setting/data and deselecting the connection opptimizer

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded an app called [Hotspot Shield](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hotspotshield.android.vpn).
All you need to so is start it and while on your school's wi-fi, it will unblock everything.

**NOTE:** This app uses alot of data so make sure you are connected to wi-fi first.

Comment: I cant even connect to the wifi in the first place

Comment: @JettC I see what you mean now, my bad :)

Comment: @Jonco98, as this doesn't answer the question, you might consider removing it (to avoid others becoming confused).